# How to jump to a site number in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I have two sites in SSRS and I want to create a action to link to switch between both sites.

Its it possible to create such a non bookmark link?

Comment: Just set the textbox property "Action" to "Go to URL" and then set the URL to whatever you need it to be

Comment: Yes, i know this method, the problem is I lose for example my entered parameter. Goal is to move between sites not to a new report instance.

Comment: You need to edit your question and explain in much more detail what you are trying to do, Mock up and exmaple of what you expect to see and what the "links" are (what would the URL be etc.)

Comment: I am looking something simmiliar to Bookmark method. With a ability to move between pages in a report without reload the report. Reloading happen if I use the "Go to Url" method, I lose with reloading my previous entered parameters.